# How to evenly spread out date data (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I'm working on a project and I'm struggling with some formats of dataframes. I have two dataframes, each containing a different number of months. I want all the months of 2013 (so 2013-01, 2013-02 ... 2013-12), which is in the second picture. I want to compare them to the storage_monhty in the first picture. However, the dates in the storage dataframe are not evenly spread, and there are less (9 months vs 12 months).
Is there a way that I can add 3 months and interpolate the corresponding data to the 'standard' format of 2013-01 etc?
Thank you in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU60l.jpg

Comment: please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [add a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)